# Trying to use AM–GM to prove an inequality

Tags: inequality

Given that $a,b,c > 0$.  I'm trying to prove $$\left(\sqrt\frac{a+b}c+\sqrt\frac{b+c}a+\sqrt\frac{c+a}b\right)^2\ge\frac{2(a+b+c)^3}{3abc}.$$  I tried directly applying AM–GM on the LHS, but I *can't* get $abc$ with degree 1 in the denominator. $$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt\frac{a+b}c+\sqrt\frac{b+c}a+\sqrt\frac{c+a}b}{3} &\ge \sqrt[3]{\sqrt\frac{a+b}c\sqrt\frac{b+c}a\sqrt\frac{c+a}b} \\
\sqrt\frac{a+b}c+\sqrt\frac{b+c}a+\sqrt\frac{c+a}b &\ge 3 \sqrt[3]{\sqrt\frac{a+b}c\sqrt\frac{b+c}a\sqrt\frac{c+a}b} \\
\left(\sqrt\frac{a+b}c+\sqrt\frac{b+c}a+\sqrt\frac{c+a}b\right)^2 &\ge 9 \sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b}c\frac{b+c}a\frac{c+a}b} \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrong inequality

Let $a=1,b=2,c=3$,then
$$LHS=(1+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2})^2=21.625\cdots$$
But
$$RHS=\dfrac{2(1+2+3)^3}{3\cdot 6}=24$$